# Как сделать разные подвалы (футеры) для разных страниц?

Tags: php

Как поменять строку

```
<?php include ("footer.php");?>
```

чтобы на главной отображался не footer.php, а footer-home.php.

На прочих страницах должен быть footer.php.

Comment: Неужели регистрироваться на куче сайтов и писать везде этот вопрос было проще, чем посидеть и подумать, как составить простое условие?

Answer (score 0):

в основном, это решается шаблонами страниц.
Но можно поставить простое условие:
если url = 'home.php', то  include ("home-footer.php"); иначе include ("footer.php");

Comment: он теперь спросит, как узнать url. тем более, что есть и более простой способ